# Como gerar urls dinâmicas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Eu estou trabalhando num projeto para escritores publicar poemas e poesias. As urls serão separadas pelo gênero, por exemplo: site.com/poemas/flores-do-campo/

No entanto, eu preciso evitar a duplicidade de títulos. Devido a isso eu pensei eu fazer um esquema semelhante ao wattpad que cria a url assim: wattpad.com/127883554-the-new-avenger

Eles inserem o código "127883554" antes do título. Porém tenho algumas dúvidas:

1 - Como gero esse código representando dia, mes e ano sem que seja 26052019 ?

2 - Como vou montar a url de modo que codigo+titulo sejam separado pelo "-".

O laravel tem algum recurso pra montar essas urls de um modo inteligente?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso na hora de cadastrar exemplo:

```
public function cadastrar(Request $request) {
       $request->validate([
            $request->titulo => 'required',
            ...
       ]);

       Model::create([
          'table_titulo' => $request->titulo,
          'table_url' => mt_rand(0, 9999999).'-'.mt_rand(0,10).$request->titulo,
          ...
       ]);

}
```

Dessa forma você cadastra a URL e titulo, na hora de acessar algo exemplo wattpad, só fazer uma rota dessa forma;

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'livroController@index');
```

controller ficara dessa forma

```
public function index(Request $request) {
     $livro = Livros::where('url', $request->only('url'))->first();

     return view('index', compact('livro'));

}
```

Faz um teste se funcionar da um Alo ai...

OBS: Se não funcionar com Request troque por `$url` o parâmetro ser recebido...